# Create week from friday

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a date column. How do I get the week starting Friday?

```
df    date          
0   2016-01-01     
1   2016-01-02     
...
```

Expected output

```
df    date          week
0   2016-01-01     2016-01-01
1   2016-01-02     2016-01-01
```

```
df['week'] = df.date - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_period`:

```
df['week'] = df.date.dt.to_period('W-THU')
df['first_day'] = df['week'].dt.start_time
```

Output:

```
   df       date                   week  first_day
0   0 2016-01-01  2016-01-01/2016-01-07 2016-01-01
1   1 2016-01-02  2016-01-01/2016-01-07 2016-01-01
```